# ¿Cómo hacer que el usuario seleccione el certificado que va a usar?

Tags: c#, .net, webservice, https

Tengo que enviar un XML a un webService con HTTPS. Me gustaría que a la hora de enviarlo me abra la ventana de selección de certificados instalados para que sea el usuario el que elija cuál quiere usar y a continuación procesar el envío con el certificado seleccionado.

Answer (score 0):

```
internal static X509Certificate2Collection CertificadoSeleccionado() 
    {            

        try
        {                
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My  , StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
            X509Certificate2Collection fcollection = (X509Certificate2Collection)collection.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);
            X509Certificate2Collection scollection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(fcollection, "Selección de Certificados", "Seleccione un certificado de la lista para firmar la factura electrónica", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection );

            X509Certificate2Enumerator Certificado = scollection.GetEnumerator();

            if (fcollection.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No hay certificados electrónicos instalados en tu equipo");
            }
            else
            {
                if (scollection.Count == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No has seleccionado ningún certificado");
                }                 
            }
            store.Close();
            return scollection;             
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            throw ex;
        }         

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

siguiendo este hilo que encontré...
¿Existe alguna forma, en .net de acceder al contenedor de certificados del usuario que consulta la web?
Por supuesto utilizando los permisos necesarios.

En caso de que no, ¿me podéis orientar con que herramienta o API puedo desarrollar una manera de que los usuarios firmen documentos usando sus certificados?
Gracias.

Comment: Hola Angel, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos

si tienes alguna duda, crea tu propia pregunta, para recibir ayuda, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/380437)